# Converting dtype('O') to dtype('<M8[ns]') because of database problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 1000 data with `timestamp` column (regular mySQL timestamp), and I split this into two, called `data1` and `data2`,

```
`data1['timestamp'].dtype`

dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Probably because one or two entry is broken, so

```
`data2['timestamp'].dtype`

dtype('O')
```

and I need to `data2['timestamp'].dtype` to be `dtype('<M8[ns]')` to do further analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'`:

```
data2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['timestamp'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I was thinking this is happen before, but I'm not sure where I get the solution